# LaTex Fillable form, remove redboxes

Tags: hyperref, forms, border

I am trying to make a fillable form. I seem to be running into some issues with the form boxes when I use \TextField

When I open the PDF There is a red box displayed around the area I can type in. I wish to remove these red boxes. Also when I go to print the PDF, it prints with a faint red box as well.

This is how the PFD looks like when I go to edit it. I am using the default Reader app on windows 10. But using Adobe reader shows me the same thing.
[image]

This is how it looks like when it prints.
[image]

I tried fixes like

```
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
```

and

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,menucolor=black,runcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

But they do not fix the issue.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,verbatim,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd, graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{caption}

%Additional Packages
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
%\usepackage[framed]{mcode}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\topmargin-2.0cm
\headheight0.0cm
\headsep0.0cm
\oddsidemargin0.0cm
\textheight23.0cm
\textwidth16.5cm
\footskip1.0cm
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{surfacecor}{Corollary 1}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture} 
\newtheorem{question}{Question} 
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsection}}
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}


\begin{document}
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf} 
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=6cm, right]{ace}
        \label{fig:Logo}
    \end{figure}

%And another one
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[name=four, width=3cm, borderwidth=0]{type here:} \\

    \TextField[name=five, width=3cm, borderwidth=0]{type here:} \\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

If someone can please fix this issue or have another alterntive to \TextFeild, please let me know. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You can make the bordercolor transparent. Then the border will not show up, even if its width is larger then 0:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[bordercolor=, name=four, width=3cm, borderwidth=1]{type here:} 

    \medskip
    \TextField[name=five, width=3cm, borderwidth=1]{type here:} 
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]